# Cookie less domain using another domain in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

I want to serve static content from a cookieless domain using htaccess. Suppose I have got 2 domains registered. 
E.g abc.com and xyz.com

abc.com is my main site where the code and all content is hosted.

If I point xyz.com to abc.com's server using a CNAME record, then is it possible to serve my static content like images using xyz.com as tld and not set cookies for it? If yes how. I have went through the articles and found htaccess tricks, but unsure how to do it specifically for a particular domain. 
Please help

Comment: Sounds to me you want to create a transparent proxy with .htaccess? Maybe this article will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205092/how-to-set-up-proxy-in-htaccess

Comment: @DanBelden : I am not sure how, but creating a subdomain and showing it as a 404 solved my issue. Atleast in pingdom it now shows 100 score for cookieless domain

Comment: Do you set any cookies in Apache? Or do you only set cookies in your php scripts?