# Run newer webserver without root permissions

Tags: php, apache, proxy, socks, userland

I want to use PHP 7 when it comes out, but my server admin refuses to upgrade past PHP 5.3.3 and I don't have root privileges. I can [run a webserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/135565/install-webserver-without-root-access) on port 1024 or higher, but I need it to be available on ports 80 and 443.

I am considering connecting to this userland webserver via a local SOCKS client [in PHP](https://github.com/clue/php-socks). Can I effectively run a PHP 7 webserver on port 80 and 443 this way, and will it be possible to handle PHP requests and sessions correctly?

Comment: Do you have any sort of apache mod_proxy installed? You could just setup an apache config rule to route requests to another port. Aside from that, IMO, this sounds horrible and would likely be slow. Perhaps you could run PHP 7 as a cgi module?

Comment: I do have mod_proxy, but my understanding is that [I cannot use an .htaccess for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205092/how-to-set-up-proxy-in-htaccess), and I don't have access to vhosts.conf. I have memcached and a netscaler, so there will be some speed-ups.

Answer (score 0):

No. Port 80 is a privileged port.