# Proxy Url .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, webserver, redirect

I'am getting an error in Gchrome Console

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com:7070/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

I can access http-bind `http://example.com:7070/`  below is my 
.htaccess file

`RewriteRule http-bind/ http://example.com:7070/`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is a reverse proxy. `http://example.com:7070/` is tecnically another source, so it's being prevented from loading.

You have a few options.

1. Configure a reverse proxy on apache config file,
2. Implement it on .htaccess like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12812041/1810128)
3. Implement [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) on `example.com:7070`