# Apache port fowarding using only .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to type

```
http://example.com
```

and access

```
http://example.com:8080
```

but I want the browser address bar still displays

```
http://example.com
```

Is it possible to do that only using the .htaccess file?

Comment: read the docs and see if the commands are allowed there: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: use `iptables` or `mod_proxy` as @MarcB suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com:8080/$1 [P]
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to another question on stackoverflow that is similar but different. You should be able to do something like this in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://example.com:8080/$1 [L,P]

ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8080/
```

This will take incoming requests and rewrite them on the Apache server and return the response from the other server internally.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12812041/1569370