# htaccess, angularjs and proxy refresh

Tags: angularjs, node.js, apache, .htaccess

I'm on a shared virtual host and there I had a homepage with angularjs <> php. The htaccess file looked like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

This worked great for refreshing or directing from nearly every URL to index.html.
But now I switched to angularjs <> nodejs. It's coupled like this:

```
angularjs <> nodejs <> service <> apache
```

So I needed a new htaccess file with a proxy it now looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:64913/$1 [P]
```

I tried to get back my old refreshing / redirecting back. But no matter what I tried it ended up giving me Errors like:

```
Error: ENOENT, stat'{some long link}'
```

Does someone know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the right way. RewriteRule can't act as a PIPE to node process. it can not be so simple.

What You should do is use [Proxypass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive of apache.
[Also  see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831594/apache-and-node-js-on-the-same-server)

Comment: The problem is i don't have any other way to access any options only .htaccess. Proxypass doesnt work with .htaccess files. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808506/can-proxypass-and-proxypassreverse-work-in-htaccess) and even look at the responses of the answer.

Comment: since you are using shared resources, I don't thing you can do this. its  better to ask your provider. in my case he suggested an alternate way of adding some extra parameter to config  file.

Comment: I guess you are stuck now. You should go for an cloud server.