# How to Hide actual web page from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

On Apache, I would like something like this:

https://myserver.com/Intro evaluates to /myserver.com/januaryintro.php

as an example.

I use htaccess and cannot make this work. I get Multiple Pages error or Page Not found.

Comment: A reason for the downvote would be helpful.

Comment: Downvote reason 1: no configuration in the question which indicate no effort in research or debugging.   Reason 2: lack of research.  This has been addressed tons of times.  Reason 3: because the guy is just mean :-)

Answer (score 0):

Proxy is the solution.  But the proxy modules need to be loaded.

And since you are using htaccess, you cannot use ProxyPass.  You are forced using RewriteRule with `[P]` flag.

ex:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/intro$ https://example.com/januaryintro.php [L,P]

ProxyPassReverse / https://example.com/januaryintro.php
```

References:

- [Can ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse work in htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808506/can-proxypass-and-proxypassreverse-work-in-htaccess)
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: Did not work. ProxyPassReverse resulted in an error.

Comment: I never mind negative comments. They are often the most useful. So looking around, I found url masking with htaccess. Didn't totally solve my issues but definitely better.