# Rewrite subdomain to directory with different host using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, cname

I have a site with the domain name `example.com` and a blog on `blog.example.com` in another host (use `cname` record to connect `blog.example.com` host's to `example.com`)
Now I want to

- http://example.com/blog

show the content from

- http://blog.example.com

I made some changes in `.htaccess` file by searches but I didn't get it.
How can I do that without copy all data on blog.example.com to example.com/blog, because I want the main site and blog be on two different hosts.

Comment: You need to setup a reverse proxy: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Comment: thanks Alex, can you explain more? I can't understand the relation between my question and this link.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12812041/773849) covers the topic.  In short, it cannot be done in the .htaccess file.

Comment: I know the reverse proxy cannot be done, you offer that and i guess you know something that i don't know :)) thanks alex