# Can htaccess return the output from another domain without issuing a 301?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

let's say I have abc.com and def.com.
On def.com, I have a `def.com/test.html` that displays "hello".

I want to make it so that if I do a `GET abc.com/something/`, it returns a `200` with the contents of `def.com/test.html` directly, **and not a `301 def.com/test.html`**. I don't want users to -know- communication between 2 servers happened.

Now, I could setup a `abc.com/.htaccess` to url rewrite to `abc.com/test.php` which would take care of echoing the contents of the other website with CURL like this:

```
<?
$url = "def.com/test.html"; //Would be received from the .htaccess's URL rewrite, say $_GET['wantedURL']
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

But, is there a way to tell the .htaccess to do the CURL by itself (or return the output of a shell script that would do so), something like the following ?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/something/$ <curl def.com/test.html> [L]
#NOT THIS: RewriteRule ^/something/$ def.com/test.html [R=301,L]
```

Of course, I would be doing that for several dynamic URLs of a given pattern, so I've just hardcoded paths to explain what I'm looking for

thanks !

--- EDIT ---

I found [Can ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse work in htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808506/can-proxypass-and-proxypassreverse-work-in-htaccess) which seems to require to put it in vhosts configuration, and that's something I want to avoid. I would prefer if it could be done via .htaccess. Trying the above in .htaccess yields what they indeed explain to be impossible: `ProxyPassReverse not allowed here`

--- EDIT 2 ---

Following @MrWhite's recommendations, I now get `No protocol handler was valid for the URL /something/. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule`

But I think everything is loaded. When I do `httpd -M | grep "proxy"` I get:

```
proxy_module (shared)
proxy_ajp_module (shared)
proxy_balancer_module (shared)
proxy_connect_module (shared)
proxy_express_module (shared)
proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
proxy_ftp_module (shared)
proxy_http_module (shared)
proxy_scgi_module (shared)
proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
```

BTW this is my vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName abc.com
    ProxyPass "/" "https://def.com/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://def.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `.htaccess` you can use the `P` (`proxy`) flag on the mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` directive to send the request via mod_proxy.

For example in the `.htaccess` file at `abc.com`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^something/$ https://def.com/test.html [P]
```

(Note, that when used in `.htaccess`, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash.)

However, this naturally requires that mod_proxy *and* related modules have already been loaded/enabled in the server config.

And if you don't set `ProxyPassReverse` in the server config (as you state, this is not allowed in `.htaccess`) then it would be trivial for the target domain (ie. `def.com`) to issue a redirect to itself and effectively *break out* of the reverse proxy. Although, this is not necessarily an issue if the target domain is in your control.

Comment: sorry I'm having trouble replying to you. so I added an "edit #2" to my post