# access pages from wordpress installed in subfolder without the subfolder in url through htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two wordpress installations, one at `example.com` and another at `example.com/landing` so what I need to do is to show the page located at `example.com/landing/page1` whenever somebody goes to `example.com/page1` without any redirects using htaccess.

I have tried various htaccess code pieces and one of them seems to work and it serves pages from the `/landing` subfolder but the pages of the existing website `example.com/pages` stops working here's the code:

```
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/landing/ [NC]
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ landing/$1 [L]
```

Is this even possible with htaccess?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I can tell you that it is probably going to be an uphill battle. CMS's, including WordPress, want to "own" their URLs. So your subfolder site is _expecting_ that that object exists at `/landing/page`, and will perform all actions as if that were the fact.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind, however, is [proxying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12812041/231316). You might be able to have Apache proxy requests for that very specific URL to the other backend. I know it sounds weird, and I know they are the same server, but it might be the safest in the long wrong without hacking the CMS's too much.

Answer (score 0):

> ... one of them seems to work and it serves pages from the `/landing` subfolder but the pages of the existing website `example.com/pages` stops working here's the code:
>
> ```
> # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/landing/ [NC]
> # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ landing/$1 [L]
> ```

Yes, as you've stated, this also rewrites *all* URLs from the WordPress installation in the root (and all assets) to the WP installation in the `/landing` subdirectory, so the existing website in the root essentially "breaks".

However, if this is "working" to display page(s) from the `/landing` site (as if they are in the root) - as you suggest (so the WP installation in the `/landing` subdirectory must already be configured correctly, ie. `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` vars set) then you should just target the `/page1` URL instead of everything. For example:

```
# Rewrite "/page1" only to the WP installation in "/landing"
RewriteRule ^page1$ landing/$0 [L]
```

The `$0` backreference contains the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (simply saves repeating `page1` in this instance). This is an alternative to explicitly capturing the entire URL-path and using `$1`. eg. `RewriteRule ^(page1)$ landing/$1 [L]`.

---

HOWEVER, this assumes you are linking to any relevant assets (CSS, JS, images, etc.) directly, so no additional URL-rewriting of these assets is necessary. If that's not the case and you also need to rewrite the relevant assets to the `/landing` subdirectory then you would need to incorporate these into the above rule (or create additional rules). For example:

```
# Rewrite "/page1" and any relevant assets to the WP installation in "/landing"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/page1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/wp-content/css/my-css.css [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/wp-content/js/my-js.js [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/wp-content/img/image1.jpg [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/wp-content/img/image2.jpg
RewriteRule . landing%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Note that you will need to be selective in what you "rewrite", otherwise you will be back to the same problem of rewriting assets that the root WP installation is dependent on and the root WP site "breaks".

Note that I used the `=` prefix-operator on the above *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives). This makes the comparison an exact string match, not a regex, so no need to escape special characters or use regex anchors etc.

Note also that the last `RewriteCond` directive does not (must not) have an `OR` flag. Otherwise, it will effectively be *unconditional* and rewrite everything again!

---

OR, you could potentially rewrite any assets (CSS, JS and images) to `/landing` that are not found in the root (if that is how assets are referenced). This saves having to explicitly identify every asset that is used, at the expense of a filesystem check. For example:

```
# Rewrite "/page1" and any assets that don't exist in the root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/page1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/.+\.(js|css|jpg|webp)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . landing%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed answer however upon modifying the first line of code that I posted in the question it seems to work with both the main website and the inner page of the other website:

```RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page1 [NC]``` I believe this is now checking if the request uri contains "page1" and then rewrites everything to the subfolder which is ```/landing```.

Comment: one more thing to note, I didn't modify the htaccess of the subfolder installation at ```example.com/landing``` and everything was a natural setup from wordpress pretty permalinks. Just modified the first line along with the rest of the code and it works great!

Comment: @JunaidSaleem "however upon modifying the first line of code that I posted in the question it seems to work" - Yes, that's basically what I'm saying in my answer. Except, if you do that then the other conditions/rule are not required and you should replace that entire 4-line rule with the 1-line rule in my answer. (_Aside:_ Why did you omit the end-of-string anchor on your regex `^/page1`? And the `NC` flag should not be used here, since it creates a potential duplicate content issue.)

Comment: @JunaidSaleem "I didn't modify the htaccess of the subfolder" - Yes, that is correct, you should not need to. This rule (in the root) is dependent on the presence of the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory. And yes, it's quite possible that you didn't need to modify anything yourself in the sub-WordPress config (WP configures itself depending on what options are set during installation). Evidently, the sub-WP install is not expecting `/landing` to be present in the URL, otherwise you'd get a 404 or external redirect.

Comment: what I am saying is that the sub-WP installation is configured like any normal WP site out of the box, it is still working when I go to ```example.com/landing/page1``` and when I go to ```example.com/page1``` it is the same page, with the same source code from the sub-WP installation which is ```example.com/landing/page1``` and I also checked the source code for assets such as images, js and css and all are pointing to the ```/landing/``` sub-WP installation which is exactly what I am trying to do which is just showing a sub-WP installed pages on the root domain without the subfolder.

Comment: @JunaidSaleem If this answered your question then please mark it as accepted, to help other readers. Upvote answers you find helpful and to show your appreciation. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to use only a little bit from the above comprehensive answer and worked it out myself so how  do I post the actual solution I ended up with?